# Select an input inside a table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

How can I show the `div` element with class `.mynote` once clicking on the `input` with `id=title`? I tried the below code, but it doesn't work.

```js
$("#title").click(function() {
  $(".mynote").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tall-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="tall-data">
        <div class="tall-note">
          <div class="mynote" style="display:none">
            some text here
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tall-data">
      <td class="tall-label">
        text ...
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tall-data">
        <input name="title" id="title">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tall-data">
      <td class="tall-label">
        text ...
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you share a fiddle of the code which you are using ?

Comment: The code you've shown in the question works fine, as you can see from the executable snippet I edited in. I'd suggest you check the console for errors, ensure you've included jQuery.js in the page, are running your jQuery code in a document.ready handler and also have only one `#title` element in the DOM

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I was including the jQuery.js in a wrong way. Thanks.

Comment: Glad you got it working. I'd suggest deleting this question then, as it was a typographical issue.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I can not delete it because it has two answers :(

Answer (score 1):

```
$( 'input#title' ).on( 'focus', function() {
    $(".mynote").show();
}).on( 'focusout', function() {
    $(".mynote").hide();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7u0r8dvw/

Answer (score 0):

```
<table class="tall-table">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="tall-data">
      <div class="tall-note">
      <div class="mynote" style="display:none">
      some text here
      </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tall-data">
    <td class="tall-label">
      text ...
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tall-data">
      <input name="title" id="title">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tall-data">
    <td class="tall-label">
      text ...
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#title").click(function() {
            $( ".mynote" ).show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This is identical to what the OP already has. How is it supposed to be of any help?